# pgadmin google cloud instance queries not executed

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have an active connection to a google cloud postgresql instance via pgadmin. unfortunately i am encountering behaviours I can`t explain. The following situations occurred

1. I tried creating some tables and sometimes it would successfully create them and sometimes not, using the exact same syntax and even when it does create the tables, inserting values also wont work right after. had the same issue with AWS.

Now I just tried to `select * from table` and received no output.

Messages Tab: `Query returned successfully in 165 msec`

Data Output Tab: `! no data output. Execute a query to get output`

My Code:

```
create table public.role (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null
);

create table public.person (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null
);

create table public.person_role_relationship (
    role int not null,
    person int not null,
    foreign key (role) references public.role (id),
    foreign key (person) references public.person (id),
    unique (role,person)
);

create table public.continent (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    unique (name)
);

create table public.provider (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    unique(name)
);

create table public.country (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    continent int not null,
    foreign key (continent) references public.continent(id),
    unique (name)
);

create table public.country_provider_relation (
    provider int not null,
    country int not null,
    foreign key (provider) references public.provider (id),
    foreign key (country) references public.country (id),
    unique (provider,country)
);

create table public.town (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    country int not null,
    foreign key (country) references public.country(id),
    unique (name)
);


create table public.bettingtype (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null
);

create table public.outcometype (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null
);

create table public.outcometype_bettingtype_relation (
    bettingtype int not null,
    outcometype int not null,
    foreign key (bettingtype) references public.bettingtype (id),
    foreign key (outcometype) references public.outcometype (id)
);

create table public.inflow (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    town int not null,
    amount float not null,
    foreign key (town) references public.town(id)
);

create table public.outflow (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    town int not null,
    amount float not null,
    foreign key (town) references public.town(id)
);

create table public.outflow_person_relationship (
    person int not null,
    outflow int not null,
    foreign key (person) references public.person (id),
    foreign key (outflow) references public.outflow (id),
    unique(person,outflow)
);

create table public.results (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null
);

create table public.bet (
    id serial primary key,
    bettingtype int not null,
    outcometype int not null,
    outflow int not null,
    inflow int,
    player int not null,
    location int not null,
    online boolean not null,
    result int not null,
    foreign key (bettingtype) references public.bettingtype (id),
    foreign key (outcometype) references public.outcometype (id),
    foreign key (outflow) references public.outflow (id),
    foreign key (inflow) references public.inflow (id),
    foreign key (player) references public.person (id),
    foreign key (location) references public.town (id),
    foreign key (result) references public.results (id)
);

insert into role (name) values ('role1'),('role2'),('role3'),('role4');
insert into person (name) values ('person1'),('person2'),('person3'),('person4'),('person5'),('person6'),('person7');
insert into continent (name) values ('continent1'),('continent2');
insert into results (name) values ('result1'),('result2'),('result3');
```

What am I not seeing?

Comment: I see no `SELECT` statement in there. Could you describe your exact clicks in more detail?

Comment: When it is not successful, what happens instead?  An error message?

Comment: What version of pgAdmin are you using?  Perhaps this is a case where a screen shot would be helpful.